# jQuery Tabs vs separate pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web-applications

I'm beginning to design a website that will have quite a few features and things to click on, etc.  This whole website isn't really spec'ed out in terms of layout, so I am designing it as I go.  Here is a sample design to give you an idea:

http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5176/5510107585_a9a15d680a.jpg

Currently, I am using jQuery tabs for tab1, tab2, etc.  However, a lot of content is going to fill up each of these tabs.  For example, a google map in one, a jQuery FullCalendar in another, a jqPlot in another, etc.

At first glance with mostly empty content, it all seems to load quickly, but perhaps there may be some performance issues as more stuff is implemented.  Already, the javascript files I'm making are becoming large.

With all that in mind, I'm wondering if this design would be better served with multiple pages instead of multiple jQuery tabs both in terms of user experience and programming effort.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery tabs definitely work better than individual pages. However, I understand your dilemma. I think that you should consider making each of the content within the page a separate file. Then, you can use the jQuery tabs with AJAX.

This will have the same effect as tabs (maybe a little longer to load), but it shouldn't be laggy or anything like that.

Here is the jQuery UI demonstration, in case you have trouble finding it:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it depends on the use of the site. If it's meant to act as a web application and you want the seamless transparency that asynchronous navigation can offer, tabs would be the way to go. You might look into "lazy-loading" techniques if you want to avoid loading all the content in your tabs, particularly if you don't anticipate users of your site to necessarily use/need the content of every tab. Otherwise, using traditional pages saves a lot of time and trouble, especially if you don't want to have to deal with emulating browser history with url events. Nothing is more frustrating to a user then clicking a tab and trying to use the "back" button to view the previous, just to be kicked out of your site unto the original referrer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked with jQuery ui tabs and some behavior were not what i wanted (the way focused state is done in jQuery UI is a mess).
Also the css part can be tricky.

I advise you to do a simple test case before any coding.